# Tooltip on an NSButton doesn't disappear after clicking on NSButton

Tags: cocoa, tooltip, nsbutton

See title, 
If I highlight over a button, I have a tooltip come up that describes the button.  However, once I click on that button, the tooltip remains up

Has anybody seen this problem, or know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, just created a method that hid all tooltips, and called it whenever a button was pressed